# Arraylist<Object []> to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList of Object[] from an Object[][] perform some changes and then getting a new Object[][] with the changes made.

However I get this compile error:

> error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to Object[][]

when performing this:

```
protected Object[][] data;
fillData();
ArrayList dlist= new ArrayList<Object[]>( Arrays.asList(data) ); //NO COMPILE ERROR
Object[] example=new Object[2]; //just to use in toArray()

String [] args= {"new data 1","new data 2"};//yeah just a typo thanks Oscar
dlist.add( args ); //Sending String instead of Object is legal thanks Oscar.

data= dlist.toArray( example ); //COMPILER ERROR incompatible...
```

I am using the wrong statement with no compiler error: 
`ArrayList dlist= new ArrayList<Object[]>( Arrays.asList(data) );`
because the output is Object[] instead of Object[][] which is what i want
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `List<Object[]> dlist= new ArrayList<Object[]>( Arrays.asList(data) );` compiles for me. What's your exact problem? Probably you didn't add the necessary imports or something.

Comment: `dlist.add(<whatever>)` works because you have declared `ArrayList dlist` which is raw, similar to declare `ArrayList<Object> dlist` which means you can store anything there.

Comment: What do you mean by *I am using the wrong command, thanks for your help*? Is your problem solved or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this piece of code and works:

```
Object[][] data = { { "hello", "world" }, { "bye", "world" } };
//convert Object[][] to List<Object[]>
List<Object[]> dlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data) );
for (Object[] o : dlist) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(o));
}
//convert List<Object[]> to Object[][]
Object[][] data2 = dlist.toArray(new Object[0][]);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data2));
```

Also, Java language doesn't work with commands, except if you refer to the command line to compile your files, but that's outside the Java programming language.

Comment: `Object[][] data2 = dlist.toArray(new Object[dlist.size()][]);` would avoid creating unnecessary garbage as well.

Comment: `Object[][] data = dlist.toArray(new Object[dlist.size()][]);` would be enough? i don't want to keep data "data". just the new.
And Luiggi 
`Object[][] data2 = dlist.toArray(new Object[0][]);`
should I put this in an iterator and replace 0 by a counter? or your statement is updating the whole two dimensional array?

Comment: @lrn2java I'm replacing the whole `Object[][]` *2d* array.

Comment: @msandiford I leave that up to the JVM.

Comment: Okey thanks `estimado`, I will continue my little proyect and then do the reading on arrays and Lists, the deepToString seems to do the trick.

Comment: Hi Luiggi.  It's not really up to the JVM, it's the implementation of `ArrayList#toArray(array)`.  From the Javadoc: "If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein.  Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this list".  Easy to avoid the reflection and unused array allocation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29

Comment: @msandiford which turns to be a very small amount of memory misused and Garbage Collector (jvm) will take care of. Seriously, misusing less than 20 bytes is not a problem and JIT may optimize it for me. Using a desired length array in this case is a micro optimization and it shouldn't be a problem unless demonstrated by a profiler. Note that if I'm working with a specific amount of memory and time-space for a specific device, then I would use plain arrays directly instead of ArrayList class.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
List<Object[]> dlist = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for(Object[] i: data) {
    dlist.add(i);
}
```

Comment: This is what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Can't see where in the question did he specify that he was trying to avoid this. Also, why?

Comment: Usage of `Arrays#asList` will suffice.

Comment: Can't see how `ArrayList<Object[]> dlist = new ArrayList<Object[]>(Arrays.asList(objects));` doesn't compile though... it works on my machine.

Comment: That's the problem, it is an unclear question and we don't know the exact problem OP has.

Comment: i get the same error: i think th issue is here: 
`dlist = new ArrayList<Object[]>( Arrays.asList(data) );`
what seems wrong is the thing on  ( ) cause it is giving an Object[] and not an Object[][] I WILL TRY TO EDIT THE QUESTION TO MAKE IT CLEAR

Comment: `ArrayList<Object[]> dlist = new ArrayList<Object[]>(Arrays.asList(objects));` that does compile sorry i made a mistake. But i think the problem is there because later in `data=dlist.toArray(example);` i get the compiler error